# Is simulated PowerPC faster than actual PowerPC?

Tags: qemu, xilinx, powerpc

I have used PowerPC chip emulated by QEMU and currently am using Xilinx Virtex II pro to execute PowerPC instructions.

On both I run a custom RTOS and measure the time taken by a task. The contents of the task does not differ between the implementations, but the time taken by it has a considerable gap.

The time taken on QEMU is around 200 microseconds, whereas time taken on Xilinx chip is about 2000 microseconds.

Why does this happen ? Shouldn't running the RTOS on hardware directly be faster than emulating it ?

Edit: the speed of both is 300 MHz

Comment: What is the clock speed on the Virtex II Pro ? 300 MHz ? What is the clock speed on the CPU you are using for emulation ?

Comment: @PaulR for both the speed is 300 MHz

Comment: There are quite a few things that can effect system performance.  What is the memory bus width and clock frequency in both systems.  Many systems will use a PLL and run the memory controller at a higher frequency than the CPU.  What's the size of the data/instruction cache of each system?  Is instruction/data prefetch enable?

Answer (score 0):

It's not inconceivable that QEMU running on some host could perform better than some other particular real hardware. In vague marketing terms, the performance of QEMU's PowerPC JIT [could get into mid-hundreds-of-MIPS on (unspecified) systems in 2010](https://web.archive.org/web/20101225074220/http://jserv.sayya.org/qemu/QEMU-JIT-Code-Generator-System-Emulation.pdf#page=7), which is comparable to a low-hundreds-of-MHz PowerPC 405 ([Xilnix Virtex II Pro Datasheet](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/data_sheets/ds083.pdf), [PowerPC 405 Core Product Overview](http://datasheets.chipdb.org/IBM/PowerPC/405/PowerPC-405-Core.pdf#page=5)).

Whether the performance difference between QEMU on whatever you are running it on and a PowerPC 405 core on your FPGA is of enough magnitude to explain the measured time difference you're seeing in whatever you're trying to run on it is a different question, and is unclear without more information.